# How to supply Git credentials from a batch file (in a sane way)?

Tags: git, batch-file

By doing it in a sane way I mean:

- Without permanently modifying the repository or system.
- Surely, without user input. All credentials must be supplied by the batch file itself (or files that go along with it).
- Using either GitHub access token or SSH.

Sure enough, this MUST be easy, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GitHub Access Token:

```
git remote add rw-origin https://%GH_TOKEN%@github.com/username'repo
                                 ^~~~~~~~~^
```

And before that

```
SET GH_TOKEN=0123456789abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to iBug's answer, adding remote isn't necessary. Don't know how I overlooked it earlier, but it can be done straight away by just specifying the URL:
git push -u https://%GH_TOKEN%@github.com/username/repo.git master